# Возможно ли из массива JSON получать данные?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Создал на JQuery многомерный массив:

```
var shed = {};
   shed['half-round'] = {
       '2100':
       {
           '2500': { 
                       'wo-polycarbonate':16300,
                       'polycarbonate':21300
                   },
           '3000': { 
                       'wo-polycarbonate':17900,
                       'polycarbonate':22900
                   },
           '3500': { 
                       'wo-polycarbonate':21600,
                       'polycarbonate':26600
                   },
           '4000': { 
                       'wo-polycarbonate':22700,
                       'polycarbonate':27700
                   },
           '4500': { 
                       'wo-polycarbonate':24800,
                       'polycarbonate':29900
                   },
           '5000': { 
                       'wo-polycarbonate':25900,
                       'polycarbonate':31000
                   },
           '5500': { 
                       'wo-polycarbonate':27600,
                       'polycarbonate':32700
                   },
           '6000': { 
                       'wo-polycarbonate':28700,
                       'polycarbonate':39300
                   }
    }
}
```

умеет ли JQuery делать выборку данных и сколько элементов в каждом элементе? Например - хочу узнать сколько элементов в элементе 2100, запрашиваю `length` - сообщается что такой функции не найдено.

Работает, вроде, только алгоритм выборки "до самого последнего хвоста", например:

```
alert(shed['half-round'][2100][2500]['wo-polycarbonate']);
```

который выдает самое дальнее значение ветви = 16300...

Запросы вида:

```
shed['half-round'][2100][2500].length
shed['half-round'][2100].length
shed.length
shed['half-round'][2100][0]
shed['half-round'][0]
```

Как-то трудно реализуемые?

Использую jquery 2.1.4.

P.S: вроде народ сравнивает JSON с XML форматом и доказывает что его абсолютно реально возможно использовать.

Comment: При чем тут вообще jquery и json?

Comment: Не путайте JSON и javascript-объекты, это хоть и очень похожие вещи, но всё-таки они немножко разные. У javascript-объектов есть такая заумная штука, как прототипное наследование, и нельзя просто так взять и посчитать длину.

Comment: Посмотрите на вот эту функцию: [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Ознакомился с вашим же ответом. Вы сами понимаете что нужно сделать, зачем оно нужно и что получиться должно? Предлагаю вопрос закрыть. Автору ознакомиться с сайтом по javascript [learn.javascript](http://learn.javascript.ru/) и после этого создать новый более конструктивный вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, вы хотите странного.

Для начала — это не массив (массивов в вопросе вообще нет) и даже не что-то из JSON, а просто объект JavaScript со всеми своими плюсами и минусами, а также с прототипным наследованием. jQuery здесь тоже нигде нет, это чистый JavaScript.

В нормальных ситуациях узнавать количество ключей объекта (aka словарь aka хэш-таблица) нужно крайне редко: к ключам просто обращаются, или же их перебирают в цикле, и всё. Вам стоит подумать над тем, чтобы вместо них использовать массивы.

Если же вам нужно хранить объекты строго упорядоченно, то вам обязательно стоит заменить это всё на массивы, потому что обычные словари/хэш-таблицы хранят всё неупорядоченно по определению, в любой реализации любого языка программирования (кроме php, лол). <sub>(Бывают необычные вроде OrderedDict в Python, но здесь речь не о них.)</sub>

---

Всё же, если вы внимательно прочитали и перечитали то, что написано выше, и всё-таки решили продолжать использовать js-объекты, то вот я накатал рекурсивную функцию, которая позволяет узнать число ключей в самом объекте и во всех потомках объекта. (Есть немного лишний код для вывода лога на страницу; надеюсь, вы сможете адаптировать функцию для своих нужд. Если рекурсивный подсчёт всех-всех потомков вам не нужен, то удалите те части функции, которая связана с `kidsLength`.)

```js
function calcLength (obj, printPrefix) {
  // printPrefix нужен только для красивого вывода на страницу
  printPrefix = printPrefix || '';

  var length = 0; // Количество непосредственных потомков
  var kidsLength = 0; // Количество всех-всех потомков
  
  // Перебираем все ключи объекта
  for (var key in obj) {
   if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      // Так как может быть прототипное наследование,
      // не все ключи могут принадлежать непосредственно объекту
      // То, что принадлежит прототипам, пропускаем
      continue;
    }

    length += 1;
    kidsLength += 1;

    // Если потомок — тоже объект, то рекурсивно считаем
    // число потомков и у него
    if (typeof obj[key] == "object") {
      kidsLength += calcLength(obj[key], printPrefix + '/' + key)[1];
    }
  }
  
  log.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
   printPrefix + ": непосредственных потомков " + length +
    ", всего потомков " + kidsLength + "\n"
  ));
  // Возвращаем вызывающему информацию о числе потомков
  return [length, kidsLength];
}



var shed = {};
shed['half-round'] = {
       '2100':
       {
         '2500': { 
           'wo-polycarbonate':16300,
           'polycarbonate':21300
         },
         '3000': { 
           'wo-polycarbonate':17900,
           'polycarbonate':22900
         },
         '3500': { 
           'wo-polycarbonate':21600,
           'polycarbonate':26600
         },
         '4000': { 
           'wo-polycarbonate':22700,
           'polycarbonate':27700
         },
         '4500': { 
           'wo-polycarbonate':24800,
           'polycarbonate':29900
         },
         '5000': { 
           'wo-polycarbonate':25900,
           'polycarbonate':31000
         },
         '5500': { 
           'wo-polycarbonate':27600,
           'polycarbonate':32700
         },
         '6000': { 
           'wo-polycarbonate':28700,
           'polycarbonate':39300
         }
    }
};

calcLength(shed, "shed");
```

```css
#log {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: я не странного хочу, а именно передвигаться по массиву не только горизонтально, но и вертикально.... Спасибо за ответ, я попробую изучить ваше видение

Comment: @095 это не массивы, это объекты javascript. Но всё равно всегда можно передвигаться по нему можно до произвольной глубины рекурсивно по образу и подобию моего примера (в общем-то так почти в любом языке программирования можно). Но с длиной конкретно в javascript «длина» объекта — понятие слишком неоднозначное (почитайте учебники, чтобы понять, почему неоднозначное), поэтому её надобно считать самостоятельно, как в моей функции

Answer (score 0):

Там нет простого ответа, потому Object. И что каждый объект в JavaScript происходит, включает в себя множество атрибутов автоматически, и точный набор атрибутов , которые вы получите , зависит от конкретного переводчика и что код выполняется перед вашими.

Таким образом вы можете осуществит подсчет именно тех атрибутов которые вам нужны.

Вот один из способов:

```
var foo = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"};
Object.prototype.foobie = 'bletch'; // add property to foo that won't be counted

var count = 0;
for (var k in foo) {
    if (foo.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
       ++count;
    }
}
alert("Found " + count + " properties specific to foo");
```

Вторая строка показывает , как другой код может добавить свойства для всех Object производных. Если убрать hasOwnProperty() проверку внутри цикла, количество недвижимости будет идти по крайней мере до 4. На странице с другой JavaScript помимо этого кода, он может быть выше , чем 4, если этот другой код также изменяет Objectпрототип.

Вы можете перебрать и другим способом 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

```
`$.each(object, function( index, value ) {
  //object[index];
  //value;
});`
```

Comment: правильно ли я понял - что этот цикл задел только первый уровень многомерного массива? Как быть с остальными ветками?

Comment: {"key1": "value1:"value11","value12", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}

Comment: _________________
вот в этом проблема, я не могу войти на другой уровень....
http://joxi.ru/E2pb1edhBRg8Nr.jpg

Comment: Вы можете перебрать и другим способом 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

`$.each(object, function( index, value ) {
  object[index];
});`

Comment: Вот такую таблицу надо обработать:

Comment: http://joxi.ru/MAjpoz1hv0MEVm.jpg

Comment: там ОБЪЕКТ в ОБЪЕКТЕ в ОБЪЕКТЕ, а не просто объект, - возможно ли это?

Comment: может я неверно код написал вида { 1, { 2, {3 ,

Comment: может так невозможно?

Comment: ушел пробовать второй способ и достукиваться до объекта вторых и третьих уровней..... спасибо

Comment: в общем, ваш ответ кроме цифры count (вроде которая тоже всегда 1 показывает, даже если добавить еще параметра 3-4) - ничего не показывает, при этом невозможно залезть выше 2го уровня......

Comment: Это вообще по-русски написано или как?